# Any workaround to pass multiple arguments to defaultdict's default_factory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, factory, defaultdict

I have a factory method called `create_food`, which takes in multiple string parameters like below:

```
def create_food(self, meat: str, vege: str) -> str:
```

I have another dictionary called `__kitchen` which uses string as key & value like below:

```
self.__kitchen: dict[str, str] = dict()
```

The `__kitchen` dictionary would take a dish name as a key value. If the dish name is not found, then it would call `create_food`, then add the food to the dictionary using the dish name as its key.

```
    food: str = self.__kitchen.get(dish)
    
    if food is None:
        food = self.create_food('ham', 'egg')
        self.__kitchen[dish] = food
    
    return self.__kitchen[dish]
```

Now, I would like to use `defaultdict` & override its `__missing__` method by using `create_food`. However, I could not find a way to pass in extra parameters like `meat`, `vege`.

```
class KitchenDefaultDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, factory: callable):
        super().__init__(factory)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise TypeError(self.default_factory)

        food: str
        food = self[key] = self.default_factory()  # how to pass meat, vege?
        return food
```

I am aware that `default_factory` in `defaultdict` **does not** take any argument at all.
Is there any workaround to pass extra arguments to `default_factory`?
Any advice & solution is welcomed.

Comment: What is the output of create_food? If kitchen key is dish name, for example ramen, then what is the value? If create_food returns string, than it is not a list of dish ingredients. It's not possible to advice anything, unless you clarify this

Comment: As for passing arguments to default_factory, well, it is default factory. It should not take any arguments, because it produces default value, while the purpose of defaultdict is to have default values for missing keys, i.e. if you need a specific value for the missing key, it is no longer a default value

Answer (score 0):

What would you pass? `key` is the dish, which is distinct from the ingredients.

What you can do is instantiate a `defaultdict` with a function that calls `create_food` with default arguments

```
self.__kitchen = defaultdict(lambda: self.create_food('ham', 'egg'))
```

If you instead want to pass `key` to the default factory, I wouldn't subclass `defaultdict`, but instead subclass `dict`.

```
class factorydict(dict):
    def __init__(self, factory: callable):
        self.factory = factory

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)

        value = self.factory(key)
        self[key] = value
        return value
```

and then instantiate `__kitchen` with one of those

```
self.__kitchen = factorydict(lambda dish: self.__create_dish(dish)) // or whatever
```

Comment: what happens if I do not have the arguments when `defaultdict` is declared? I only know the arguments like `ham`, `egg` when the `key` is used to index the `defaultdict`?